# How can I get the type of a variable in RHINO?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

I'm translating some code that use SpiderMonkey to RHINO, 
and it uses the method JSVAL_IS_INT(val) where 'val' is a jsval(SpiderMonkey code), 
and I tried to use toNumber(val) of RHINO, where 'val' is an instance of Object, 
but it seems tha toNumber doesn't check the type of 'val'.

This is the code of a similar case, with toBoolean:

```
    ContextTest ct = new ContextTest();
    ct.val = "lol";
    System.out.println(Context.toBoolean(ct.val));
    System.out.println(ct.val);
```

This shows:

```
true
lol
```

But toBoolean() shouldn't return true.

Comment: Can you attache some code and result of invoking toNumber function (exception thrown, errors etc.)? Is the argument of toNumber result of another rhino function invokation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context methods such as toBoolean, toNumber aren't good to checking types. Those methods try to do "forced conversion" and they don't check types.
In Your example toBoolean returns true because string is not empty (see [context class source](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler-rhino/source/browse/src/org/mozilla/javascript/Context.java?r=4fdefdd0af7b17604f0fbc979c6bae0d317a5f5e&spec=svn50e933d402d2160635f778ecef297c492b8a15ee)).

To check/convert value to integer use:

```
  if(val instanceof Integer) {
           Integer valInt = (Integer) val;
           System.out.println(valInt);
        } else if(val instanceof Scriptable) { //Rhino class embedes any js value
           Scriptable s = (Scriptable) val;
           String className = s.getClassName();// ECMA class name
           System.out.println(className);
           if(className.toLowerCase().equals("number")) {
              System.out.println(Context.toNumber(val)); 
           }
        }
```